http test when duplicate user exist,
I try to test my http post request for getting code 200 ( when no duplicate user) and 409 ( when duplicate user exist as below
@PostMapping("/register")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@RequestBody Account account) {

    //int i=accountService.addUser(account);
    final Account accounts=accountRepository.findByUsername(account.getUsername());
    if (accounts==null ){
        return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.OK);  

    }else{
        return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.CONFLICT); 
    }
   

}

test :
I get 200 for no duplicate
but when i test for second test can not find 409 ( it give error "expected 409 but result 200"
test :
I get 200 for no duplicate
but when i test for second test can not find 409 ( it give error "expected 409 but result 200"
